# Initial zoom to GeoJSON object from file (.js) in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, zoom, visual-studio-code

I am building a viewer with Leaflet API and OpenStreetMap base. I want that when I enter this viewer it shows me immediately in the initial visualization the extension of my layer that I am using. For this, I am using the getBounds function together with fitBounds, but it doesn't work for me. I send the code:

```
var mapCenter = [-34.5, -70.65];

var myMap = L.map('map').setView(mapCenter, 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(myMap);

L.control.scale({
    metric: true,
    imperial: false,
    maxWidth: 200,
    position: 'bottomleft', 
    updateWhenIdle: true,
    scaleWidth: 0.5,
    scaleRatio: 50000 
}).addTo(myMap);

var line_style ={
    "color": '#8d7696',
    "weight":  6,
};

L.geoJson(line, {style: line_style}).addTo(myMap);

var bounds = line.getBounds();
myMap.fitbBounds(bounds); `
```

When I open the HTML the console gives me the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: line.getBounds is not a function" map.js:27

I am loading the "line.js" file as a .js file from another folder, but in the same directory, as shown below:

[image]

In this file I have declared the variable: "var line", so I doubt that this is the problem, since the viewer works, but it keeps showing me the coordinates that are shown at the beginning of the code, in the "mapCenter" variable, but such As I said at the beginning, I want the viewer to start with the spatial extension of the "line.js" file.

The code of the GeoJSON file, named "line", with a .js extension, is as follows:

```
   var line = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection", 
    "name": "Linea_3", 
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
     "features": [
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "FID_1": 12, "objectid": 0, "id": null, "lenght": 0.0, "nombre": "LINEA DE METRO PROYECTADA", "linea": "LINEA 3", "layer": "LINEA DE METRO PROYECTADA", "shape_leng": 0.0, "Shape__Len": 24222.569736400001, "GlobalID": "58e3e888-c17d-4ad0-8c04-e163f7756d48" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": 
        [ [ [-70.689407292596499, -33.3665141168809], [-70.689158441804807, -33.367451093236603], [-70.687724919860102, -33.371315140984798], 
        [-70.685630872778106, -33.374845020541599], [-70.683858549305398, -33.377505314888403], [-70.683490279792295, -33.379345325424403],
         [-70.6826087880751, -33.381620222582001], [-70.681633000420504, -33.383068206493498], [-70.679181244669294, -33.385924053182698], 
         [-70.674814260725398, -33.391240889025298], [-70.673216942858005, -33.393740993165402], [-70.672194192022602, -33.395332048692602], 
         [-70.6707962951577, -33.396892997307901], [-70.669628861792305, -33.397916624979999], [-70.668560143349296, -33.398765748903102], 
         [-70.665778365739897, -33.401255938052302], [-70.663681228297307, -33.403558208610399], [-70.661372832930098, -33.406138211595703], 
         [-70.660791071660498, -33.407304582764603], [-70.659615864767503, -33.410298795723797], [-70.658297992687693, -33.413458265164898], 
         [-70.657087680992106, -33.415829990397903], [-70.656612709092897, -33.416911441048804], [-70.656015441093899, -33.4196465139539], 
         [-70.652865560613506, -33.4316842615046], [-70.653249836077705, -33.433079818599403], [-70.653092164593502, -33.434085204644497], 
         [-70.652915054584199, -33.435398995100499], [-70.652561790907896, -33.437535234800301], [-70.652231610323796, -33.440198145719002], 
         [-70.652000109986005, -33.4414382502911], [-70.651642257730401, -33.443995100880798], [-70.648989023693005, -33.459627888068503], 
         [-70.640988574420504, -33.457918598061198], [-70.631968263338294, -33.456018172154899], [-70.6296845612586, -33.455475801589699], 
         [-70.628255121455595, -33.455123531872097], [-70.629009648576996, -33.452483472622099], [-70.625578237333201, -33.452277550653598], 
         [-70.622119430249697, -33.453717478373903], [-70.617412260121, -33.452956547923399], [-70.612729283072696, -33.453338603603399], 
         [-70.607139641769706, -33.453929274518202], [-70.602681078206203, -33.454434606660399], [-70.597328706658502, -33.454987735551597],
          [-70.593923019472797, -33.455330837990999], [-70.589188341817604, -33.455516598432901], [-70.586892245503194, -33.455585989398301], 
          [-70.585839642987494, -33.455477984597799], [-70.583461045903505, -33.454917803272203], [-70.582099470136697, -33.454760320995497], 
          [-70.580060729459305, -33.454537809631802], [-70.578608041467305, -33.454425950180202], [-70.576166792872499, -33.454280658323199], 
          [-70.575779239392006, -33.454153448851699], [-70.574939391941498, -33.453496027500201], [-70.574637417550903, -33.453367407532802], 
          [-70.574224210587502, -33.453325622544199], [-70.572729233411707, -33.453431876225501], [-70.570526017784999, -33.453535268876102], 
          [-70.568090443783404, -33.453302324346502], [-70.567012723161795, -33.453247848506102], [-70.558938536388595, -33.452191894008401]]] } }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser debugger console or network section? Please also edit your question and add content of `line.js`.

Comment: Ahh, yes, this one: "Uncaught TypeError: line.getBounds is not a function", map.js:27

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to get bounds of GeoJSON object instead of GeoJSON layer. You also have one 'b' too many in your `myMap.fitbBounds(bounds)` statement.

It should be:

```
var layer = L.geoJson(line, {style: line_style}).addTo(myMap);
var bounds = layer.getBounds();
myMap.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the display is still the same, but at least it doesn't tell me that "getBounds" is not a function anymore.

Comment: Did you leave `myMap.fitbBounds(bounds);` in the code? It's necessary. What about errors in the browser debugger?

Comment: I took out myMapFitBounds(bounds) and only left the two lines that you proposed.
Regarding the errors, when I put your two lines in the code the console doesn't give me any error, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Line `myMap.fitbBounds(bounds);` is needed. I had just put lines that have to be changed in my answer. It's edited now.

Comment: I put the 3 lines, but it keeps starting the page by zooming in on the coordinates of the "mapCenter" variable and not on the extent of the "line" layer. When querying the console, the error remains the same: "Uncaught TypeError: myMap.fitbBounds is not a functio at map.js:26:7".

Comment: Please edit your question and add content of your `line.js` file.

Comment: I already wrote the code of the file and changed the theme subject

Comment: There is a typo in your `myMap.fitbBounds(bounds);` statement, one "b" too many. I didn't notice it before, just copied your code. Now that I tested it, it became obvious. See modified answer.

Comment: That detail worked!